# Git Ignore updates on a folder

Tags: git

I have a project on Github which I develop locally before uploading the changes. I then download the changes on a production server. The methodology is very simple:

My computer:

```
git add .
git commit -m ""
git push -u origin master
```

Server:

```
git pull
```

The problem is that, in my project in Django, there are a pair of folder whose content affect when uploaded on the server: The migrations folder, and the media folder. The first one cause that when I do the makemigrations on the server, it says me that there are no changes to do, and the media folder add files that are not required. I normally have to delete all the changes on these folders manually while downloaded on the server.

Is there a way in which, when I do the `git add .` these 2 folders are never included? At least until I say that they should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly I didn't find a good basic answer to this question.

Add a file called `.gitignore`. That file you can specify a file pattern per line of things to ignore. Wildcard characters work too.  Something like:

```
*.pyc  # ignore all pyc files
path/to/your/media*
# etc ...
```

Commit the .gitignore file.

If the files are already committed to your repository you can remove them with `git rm --cached your/files`.  Add `-r` as well if you're removing a directory. They'll stay on disk but be removed from your git repo. Note that when you pull on the server they may be removed. In that case you'll want to back them up and then add them back manually. Since you committed `.gitignore` above they should then be ignored on the server as well.

Another (IMHO better) way to handle this is to create a "production" branch or tag and have the server track that. That way you can keep working in master and then merge changes to your production branch once they are tested. Easier to keep track of different versions of files this way as well.

Comment: It's an option. I'll wait to see if anyone else have an answer, if not, i'll try the first. Thanks!